# Debugging Python when both PyDev and CDT natures in same Eclipse project

Tags: python, c++, eclipse, pydev

Eclipse 4.5 (Mars) / Windows 7

I have an Eclipse C/C++ Makefile project that has both Python and C/C++ code. The source code is checked-out from an SVN repository. The build environment is via a MSYS shell using a project specific configuration script to create all Makefiles in the top/sub-directories and 'make', 'make install' to build.

My .project file has both the PyDev and CDT natures configured.

I can switch between the PyDev and C/C++ perspectives and browse code including right-clicking on a symbol and 'open declaration'.

The 'Debug' perspective appears to be specific to the C/C++ perspective.

Do you have experience with configuring an Eclipse project that allows you to debug both Python and C/C++ code?

Comment: Here is what appears to be working:

Answer (score 1):

After 'googling' around the internet, here is what appears to be working for my particular situation:

1. Create a C/C++ project (empty makefile project). This produces the following 3 files in my top-level local SVN check-out directory:

.settings
.cproject
.project

Note: I keep my Eclipse workspace separate from my Eclipse project.

2. Create a separate Python project that is outside of the local SVN check-out directory.

Note: This Eclipse Python project is in my Eclipse workspace.

This creates the following 2 files:

.pydevproject
.project

3. Copy the .pydevproject to the directory containing the .settings, .cproject, and .project files.
4. Copy the Python 'nature' elements from the Python .project file to the CDT .project file.
5. Restart Eclipse if it had been running while editing the dot (.) files.
6. Finally, get into the "C/C++ Perspective". In the 'Project Explorer" window, pull down the 'View Menu".

Select 'Customize View...'.
Select the 'Content' tab.
Uncheck the 'PyDev Navigator Content' option.

Comment: Verified this is effective with Eclipse CDT 2023-03.